# Adding the reporting subject in passive voice with reported verb

Tags: passive-voice

Take a look at this example :

> Henry said a subject did something

Now if I use the passive voice to report this, it can go like :

> The subject was said to do something

But I want to add that Henry is the reporter, should I add "by Henry" after the reported verb or at the end of the sentence ?

Comment: Both are grammatically correct. I prefer "The subject was said by Henry to do something." only because it avoids the ambiguity that maybe the subject was doing something by Henry.

Answer (score 1):

Either one works, but the first one sounds better to my native ear; however, we normally drop the "by Henry" part in speech when it can be assumed who said it.

> "John was said **by Henry** to do something."
>
> or
>
> "John was said to do something **by Henry**."